# Windows 10 Sleep Options Missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I used to be able to put my computer to sleep but suddenly the setting has been completely removed.

What I have already done:
I checked the power options and it is missing from there as well.
I made sure that showing the sleep option was enabled in the group policy editor.
I changed CsEnabled to 1 in regedit.
I ran powercfg /a  and for some reason, it says that the system firmware doesn't support sleep even though it was working a few days ago.
I both rolled back and updated my graphics card, even with a clean driver installation, to no avail.
I did a clean install of windows to the previous build.
I looked through my bios settings to find any sleep-related settings, but there wasn't much.

How do I bring my sleep option back?

Comment: what graphics you have ??  did u update graphics drivers from device manager ??TBH device manager is useless for updating drivers.

Comment: I have an RTX 2080, and its fully updated.